# Security Group membership not updating in SharePoint Online

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, active-directory

We have recently setup SharePoint Online and it has all been going well until...

A few new people have joined and they have been added to their teams AD Security Group. This security group is then referenced inside a SharePoint Group for permissions, as this was previously the recommended configuration. However these new users don't appear in SharePoint.

I have tried/checked the following:

- The users are being synced across using DirSync, looking at the metaverse it's all correct.
- The users are visible in Office 365 Security Groups settings as expected. (365 Admin Center -> Users and Groups -> Security Groups)
- Manually adding additional people into the SharePoint Group (rather than AD) to try and force a crawl of users ACLs from the AD group.
- There is no difference in AD between these Security Groups and others.

Some AD groups do update correctly after an hour or so but just not the team groups.

I did look at the following which was very interesting but didn't help in this instance:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/05/06/clarifying-guidance-on-sharepoint-security-groups-versus-active-directory-domain-services-groups.aspx

Any suggestions would be welcome.